# Does Firebase send data even if it is not changed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My android application reads some data from Firebase every time when the app is opened. It uses Firebase Realtime Database. My question is, when the data is not changed since the last time the application is opened, will Firebase still send the whole unchanged data?

The reason I am asking this is, if the answer is yes, I will add a field into the database table which will hold the date of the last time the data changed, so that I will check it first to see if the data has changed and then will only read if it has. Thus, I will prevent unnecessary reads and debts from Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

answer is no the firebase caches the data locally if you don't disable this explicitly, but the listeners will still be called for cached data even though no new data is fetched [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) are the docs for more details.